# How to read continually appended data from a file after the EOF has been reached once? (Mac OS 10.8)

Tags: file-io, d

**EDIT: This only seems to apply to Mac OS. Ubuntu works just fine.**

I have a simple problem, I want to open a file and read data from it. When the file changes, i will read more data. The trouble is i only want to open the file once.

```
import std.c.stdio;
import core.thread;

void main(string[] args)
{
    char[1024] buffer;

    FILE* file = fopen("text.txt", "r");

    printf("First Read:\n");

    while(fgets(buffer.ptr, buffer.length, file) !is null)
    {
        printf("%s", buffer.ptr);
    }

    clearerr(file);

    Thread.sleep(dur!("seconds")(5));

    printf("Second Read:\n");

    while(fgets(buffer.ptr, buffer.length, file) !is null)
    {
        printf("%s", buffer.ptr);
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

I read the file, then when its paused, i add new lines to the opened file. When the program resumes it totally ignores the new lines. doh!

I guess this is the result of buffering somewhere so i've tried all sorts to try and escape this behaviour, including:

```
clearerr()
fseek()
fflush()
```

Nothing seems to work. What am i missing? It must be something simple. Any ideas?

I'm primarily using Linux/Mac OS.

Comment: I've tagged this as C as the code posted above is almost 90% C and someone who knows C well will be able to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of where you last read the file using ftell().  At EOF, rewind(),
wait a short while, fseek() to the last offset in the file you recorded and try a read operation.  IF EOF,  rewind(), else read new line(s).

PS: somebody who did not read you comment will ding you for the "C code" which has problems.  You might want to fix it if you know C.  Or put a BOLDED disclaimer at the top.